# How to research a series, when only some elements are available

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want something like the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, but for series, not sequences. I'd like to know the name of a series, in what natural phenomenon it happens and so on.

Comment: A series is just a sequence of partial sums of another sequence.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: still,  16,8,4,2,1 does not output half-life in the site above. I need a way for finding things like this (but not that obvious).

Comment: Have you tried wolframalpha?